# does a cartoDB world shapefile exist?

Tags: shapefile, carto, global

Does anyone know what cartoDB uses for country boundaries on their standard basemaps e.g. cartodb world flat blue? A shapefile would be really useful as doing global maps (using country polygons) look awful if they don't line up nicely. I've looked in the data library but couldn't find anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repo for the new CartoDB Basemaps is Open Source and available here: https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb-basemaps

They're generated by a variety of data, but the whole list is available [here](https://github.com/CartoDB/CartoDB-basemaps/blob/master/datasets.txt):

```
https://github.com/CartoDB/CartoDB-basemaps/raw/master/data/z4to10.json
http://common-data.cartodb.net.s3.amazonaws.com/basemap_datasets/continents_900913.zip
http://common-data.cartodb.net.s3.amazonaws.com/basemap_datasets/ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces_lines_shp.zip
http://common-data.cartodb.net.s3.amazonaws.com/basemap_datasets/ne_10m_geography_marine_polys.zip
http://common-data.cartodb.net.s3.amazonaws.com/basemap_datasets/ne_50m_geography_marine_polys.zip
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_countries_lakes.zip
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_boundary_lines_land.zip
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces.zip
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces_lines.zip
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_roads.zip
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/physical/ne_10m_lakes.zip
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_airports.zip
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_populated_places_simple.zip
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/physical/ne_10m_rivers_lake_centerlines.zip
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_urban_areas.zip
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_boundary_lines_map_units.zip
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/50m/cultural/ne_50m_admin_0_countries_lakes.zip
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/50m/cultural/ne_50m_admin_1_states_provinces.zip
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/50m/cultural/ne_50m_admin_1_states_provinces_lines.zip
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/50m/physical/ne_50m_land.zip
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/50m/physical/ne_50m_lakes.zip
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/50m/cultural/ne_50m_populated_places_simple.zip
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/50m/physical/ne_50m_rivers_lake_centerlines.zip
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/50m/cultural/ne_50m_urban_areas.zip
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/110m/physical/ne_110m_geography_marine_polys.zip
http://data.openstreetmapdata.com/simplified-land-polygons-complete-3857.zip
http://data.openstreetmapdata.com/water-polygons-split-3857.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably http://www.naturalearthdata.com/ or https://www.openstreetmap.org/ data, both freely available (depending on your use case).

Comment: Thanks bugmenot123, I'll check both of those options and report back on any results. I couldn't find anything in the cartoDB docs.